# Create Date Object by providing only value of time

Tags: javascript

I want to create a new Date Object by providing values of hours and minutes only.
The date can be today's date, it's only the time i am concerned with

Comment: Be more precise or post you code

Comment: Try to better explain what you mean. You want to create the Date object providing only the time? You can do something like this but you have to pass some date. I totally don't understand the second sentence from your question.

Comment: @KrzysztofDąbrowski i have edited my question. I want to create a date object with the values of hours and minutes provided by me explicitly

Answer (score 3):

You can use the functions `setHours()` and `setMinutes()` to explicitly set the time for a `Date` object:

```
// Create a Date Object:
var myDate = new Date();
// Set the minutes and hours:
myDate.setHours(20);
myDate.setMinutes(30);
```

Here the time is set with the current date.

```js
// Create a Date Object:
var myDate = new Date();
// Set the minutes and hours:
myDate.setHours(20);
myDate.setMinutes(30);
// Let's see the time:
console.log(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a `Date`, it always stores some date but you can ignore it. You can pass whatever date you wish and care only about time.

```js
const myTime = new Date("2000-01-01 13:31");

console.log(myTime.getHours(), myTime.getMinutes());
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar "totally wrong" - big words. The only part that one could consider wrong is "you have to provide" since you actually don't have to provide any arguments, then you will get the current date and time. Edited, just to be clear. Cheers.

Comment: Er... I didn't say totally wrong. Well... This is also a way to make it work... :)